How to substitute so that I can proceed with this Integral?
I need to show that
$$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{\displaystyle (x-\mu)}{\displaystyle \sigma}} \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot \exp\big(-\frac{\displaystyle v^2}{\displaystyle 2}\big)\cdot dv = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\displaystyle x} \frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} \cdot \exp\big(-\frac{\displaystyle (u-\mu)^2}{\displaystyle 2\sigma^2}\big)\cdot du $$
How can I susbtitute here in order to get there?

Better to not use the same variable in the two integrals to make it clearer

You just literally set $t$ equal to the expression in the upper bound.

not exactly @EgorLarionov?

I got it, one needs to substitute $u(v)=\mu + v \cdot \sigma $.

Mate, literally what I told you in the comments. :)) Not mad, though, happy you’ve solved it.
